# easyui conflict in jquery page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a full site in jQuery. Today I tried to add table users from `easyUI` but it is not working. In my site each page is loaded with hash, I think here is the problem, but I cannot find it.

This is the site with login credentials:

- [swapes.com](http://swapes.com)
- Login: `xdesign`
- Password: `carina`

The button call page hash is like:

```
<a class="sub-meniu" onclick="$('#content').load('sections/users.php?what=premium-users&rand='+Math.random()); window.location.hash = 'premium-members'; ">Premium Users</a>
```

When I click this button, need call the page `users.php` without refreshing the page. But this page just loads the content of this user table without the effect from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
```

This js is added in home page, but is not working. Maybe for incompatibility with what?

Comment: I wouldn't place JS logic into the `onclick` attribute but instead into a separate `.js` file (or at least into a `<script>`).

Comment: You have to apply some functions of easyUI to make things work, not just call it on your home page. Do you have more details about which kind of functions you apply once the content is loaded from users.php?